# AJAX Post request encoding

Tags: jquery, c++, ajax, post, encoding

I'm implementing an HTTP server in C++, and sending Ajax POST requests to it via jQuery.

I have a form on one of my pages that I submit using this code:

```
$('#create-event form').submit(function(e) {
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr('action');
    $.ajax({
        url : formURL,
        type: 'POST',
        data : postData,
        contentType: 'text/plain'
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

When I receive this request in my C++, the last ~10 characters of the query parameters are a garbled mess, as if the encoding is wrong. The thing is, I have many of these type of forms, and this same garbling was happening to other forms, until I added the `contentType: 'text/plain'` field. Now this form is the only one where this encoding problem is happening.

Is there any other type of encoding field that I can set to prevent this garbling? I've tried everything that I can find and nothing has helped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've spent hours on this already.

EDIT:
I now convert to unix timestamp client-side and there's no garbling, it must have had something to do with the URL-encoded space and colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to create a query string, you should try using `$(this).serialize()` instead of serialize array.

```
$('#create-event form').submit(function(e) {
    var postData = $(this).serialize();
    var formURL = $(this).attr('action');
    $.ajax({
        url : formURL,
        type: 'POST',
        data : postData,
        contentType: 'text/plain'
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're right, so I switched to .serialize(). It didn't change anything however.

Comment: and did you remove the contentType?

Comment: Removing the contentType just made the garbling worse, as it usually does.

Comment: what does serialize look like; just do console.log(postData) in dev tools and `command+option+i` in chrome and show me

Comment: postData is `name=myEvent&datetime=2014-12-10+10%3A30&group-name=myGroup`, which is what I want to receive on the server side. When I receive it, everything past the last ampersand is garbled.

Comment: instead of sending the formatted date if you were to send a unix timestamp with `Date.now();` or `someDate.getTime();` and format server-side, im wondering if that'd help

Comment: I now convert to unix timestamp client-side and there's no garbling, it must have had something to do with the URL-encoded space and colon. Thanks!